# Formato Telefónico C#

Tags: c#

**C#
Quiero saber cual es la manera correcta de hacer lo siguiente:**

ingresar valores en una text box por ejemplo: 5615dgh6fsh4h4b4df567890
y que de ahí lo muestre en otra text box de la siguiente manera: (644)456-7890
es decir que solo tome los últimos 10 numero ingresados de la cadena de caracteres y los demás los ignore así como a las letras

pensé hacerlo con un subtring pero no se si sea la manera correcta.

Espero me puedan ayudar Buen dia.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluí que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para tomar solo los numeros de la cadena podrias usar `regular expresion`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         string input = "5615dgh6fsh4h4b4df567890";
         string nros = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "");

         Console.WriteLine(nros);

    }
}
```

Con esto obtendras una cadena con el resultado "56156444567890"

Ahora si necesita 3 grupos de numeros podrias obtenerlos son el `Substring()`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         string input = "5615dgh6fsh4h4b4df567890";
         string nros = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "");

         Console.WriteLine(nros);

         string[] partes = new string[3];
         partes[0] = nros.Substring(0, 3);
         partes[1] = nros.Substring(3, 3);
         partes[2] = nros.Substring(6, 4);


         string telFormat = string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", partes);

         Console.WriteLine(telFormat);

    }
}
```

Aqui no puse la validacion si el largo del string alcanza para tomar todas las partes

Comment: Enterado!! Gracias por tu repuesta!!

una ultima pregunta entonces para tomar los últimos 10 valores los tomo con un for y un subtring o solo con el substring??

Nuevamente Agradezco la atención prestada hacia mi solicitud buen dia!!

Comment: el Substring() toma desde el inicio, para tomar solo 10 podrias primero aplicar un `string last10 = nros.Substring(nros.Length - 1, 10);` teniendo esto aplicas el substring() para tomar cada parte

Comment: agradezco mucho tu apoyo ten un excelente dia